# Bash: How to add text to a .MS Word (doc) file or an .html file?

Tags: html, bash, sed, .doc

I am a beginner in bash and have been trying to solve one annoying problem - I cannot add text to a MS Word (`.doc`) file.

I managed to extract text but not insert one. I tried using `sed` command but it ruins the file - I suppose because it adds the text to the file's 'source code' (not sure if that is the correct term). I also tried adding text to an `.html` file (using the same commands) and it still doesn't work. It only works with a simple .txt file.

Commands I have tried:

```
$: sed -i 'a/existingTest/newText' MyFile.doc
```

OR

```
$: sed "/existingText/a newText" MyFile.doc
# I use "existingTest" to identify the location where I want to append my newText.
```

With both commands the text is added (whether it is applied on a .doc or .html file) inside the 'source code' which makes the file unreadable.

Does anyone knows a way to add text to a .doc or an .html file? Preferably a solution that a beginner will understand but I will welcome anything :D

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can deal with MS Word (a bunch of xml zipped together) in this way

Comment: html should work with sed, though I am not sure if it is your syntax issue. can you post an example of the HTML you are trying to change?

Comment: Are you sure you are working with `*.doc` format which is outdated almost 20 years ago? If it is `*.docx`, once unzip the docx file, find the file which contains the target text, edit it by replacing the text, then zip the files again.

Comment: I am using .doc file. Maybe I can start using .docx, it might make it easier.

About the .html file, it is a normal html file. I have just inserted some text inside for testing and used the commands I mentioned above in my post. Then the new text gets inserted in the source code, instead of as a normal line in the file.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As for the .html file, can you provide an example you tested so I can reproduce the problem? It will be better to update your question with the text of .html file rather than writing it in the comment. BR.

Answer (score 0):

If your MS Word file has `*.docx` extention, would you please try:

```
unzip MyFile.docx
sed -i 'a/existingTest/newText' word/document.xml
zip -f MyFile.docx
```

As Bing Wang comments, docx document is a zipped file. Then once unzip the file, edit, then update the zip file reflecting the edit.

Comment: Thank you. I will convert my files to docx first (from doc) and then apply your method.

Comment: I've understood you are actually handling with doc files. It is a good idea to convert them to docx at first. While docx file is composed of `standard` xml files, doc file is Microsoft proprietary format and it is not easy to parse without Microsoft API.